# Huawei MA5683T OLT and PD IPv6

Tags: dhcpv6

I am trying to give to my customers IPv6 prefix vía DHCPv6-PD. As IT is a FTTH Network, i configure the onts with DhcpV6-PD. The OLT is my relay agent to an ISC-DHCP-Server V6. The prefix is delegated but in difference as it happens when a cisco router is acting as a dhcpv6 server, the OLT is not adding a static route to the prefix so IT is not globally visible. If i add the route manually everything works as IT should. I suppose that IT has to be a command to solve this but i haven't found it...Any experience with MA5683T?